# Connection to docker container gets lost if concurrent requests are made

Tags: mongodb, docker

i have a mongodb container that can be created using the following command:

> ```
> docker run  --ulimit nofile=64000:64000 -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=root -e MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -p 27017:27017 --name test-mongo mongo
> ```

I'm able to connect to mongodb without problems but every time i issue many concurrent requests i get the error "connection refused".  While it is still possible to connect to the container using "docker exec" the port is no longer visible from host using netstat.

I have tested the setup on 2 more computers running ubuntu 18.04 and the issue is not present on those. To complicate matters further, when the mongo container is created together with mongo-express using docker-compose file, mongo-express is able to access mongodb even after the port disappears from the host machine.

I have a feeling the problem is with my linux host but i can't figure out the problem.

Comment: Review mongod log and verify it's not crashing.

Comment: I don't think mongodb is crashing. mongodb is still accessible from mongo express. the logs have the message: "Interrupted operation as its client disconnected"

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling docker solved the problem.